# Getting LatLng from adress

Tags: android, kotlin, geocoder

I am developing an android application and in that application, I want to search for places on a map without using places.api. is there a way to get LatLng from a given address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get address from Latng by using Geocoder,please check below code

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;
    GeoPoint p1 = null;
    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
        if (address==null) {
           return null;
        }
        Address location=address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new G`enter code here`eoPoint((double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                          (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
        return p1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Emad thank u soo much for helping out. can you please tell me how to check for invalid entry of address?